# Is CORS protection ( Same origin policy ) reliable?

Tags: http, csrf, same-origin-policy

I have anti-crsf mechanism in my applications but I wonder, is it really necessary? Can I rely solely on same origin policy to protect my users from cross site resource forging attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same-origin policy only prevents Cross-Site Scripting which otherwise would be possible even for well-written applications. But it won't help with CSRF, for example, if a malicious site includes code like this:

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('attack').submit();">
    <form id="attack" action="http://victim/admin/add-user">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="badguy"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="asdf394y"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="role" value="admin"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

The attacker won't be able to read the response, but here it's not needed.